# Value cannot be null.\ Parameter name: source when mapping dynamic object to IQueriable<Class>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I'm using Entity Framework to move data out of a DB. The value I'm selecting from the db is a dynamic object, as in "select new { a = db.a, b = db.b }". I then try to return that as IQueryable object and get a "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source" exception.

The code that returns this looks something like this:

`return query as IQueryable<Class>`

I can't modify the select statement so it looks like this "select new Class { a = db.a, b = db.b }" because EF gives me a "you can't do that!" error.

Any suggestions on how I can manage this? I need it as that IQueryable because I use some static extensions to further modify the IQueryable for Filtering/Sorting/Paging. I'm not really sure if I can apply all of that to a dynamic object.

Comment: `...as IQueryable<Class>` is likely returning null because `query` isn't `IQueryable<Class>`. Show us more code though, we can't help without it.

Comment: You are missing parenthesis : Select(db =>  new Class() { a = db.a, b = db.b })

Comment: @jdweng Not if you are using pure Linq and not fluent syntax. Also, the parens are not required.

Comment: @ DavidG

Yes, I feared that was the case, but can I get it to IQueryable<Class>? Is it possible? I have some static extension classes that I need to handle sorting and filtering and it won't let me extend a dynamic object. I suppose I can turn them into static non extension classes, but... not sure if it's worth it or not. As to showing more code, not sure what to show since it boils down to getting that dynamic select into an IQueriable<Class>.

Comment: @EDanaII - You need to show us all the relevant code or delete the question. Right now the correct answer is `query as IQueryable<Class> == null`.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer. I was setting query to be var query and it was rejecting it where I did select new Class { }. That was causing the other "you can't do that!" error. When I switched to IQueryable query = ... it worked fine. Sigh... that's what I get for being tired and overworked...